# How to double-quote list elements in printed representation?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list:

`[1,2,3,'a',4,'g']`

I want to print this list with each element double-quoted:

> ["1","2","3","a","4","g"]

How to add double quotes on every element in a printed list?

## Context

I'm trying to solve the fizzbuzz problem, but my code produces an error when I try to return `list1`

```
n = 5
rangeOfList = range(1,n+1)
list1 = list(rangeOfList)
print(list1)

condition1 = "FizzBuzz"
condition2 = "Fizz"
condition3 = "Buzz"

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] % 3 == 0 and list1[i] % 5 == 0:
        list1[i] = condition1
    elif list1[i] % 3 == 0:
        list1[i] = condition2
    elif list1[i] % 5 == 0:
        list1[i] = condition3

print(list1)
```

This prints:

> [1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz']

I want to have double quotes on each element  >>

> ["1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz"]

Comment: that is not a valid python list

Comment: @AlwaysSunny: It *could* be a valid list if `a` and `g` were defined.

Comment: They would have to each  contain a string with their variable name though.

Comment: can you add double quotes to every element of the list

Comment: I suspect you don't have a list, but a *string* that looks like a list (say, `'[1,2,3,a,4,g]'`).

Comment: There's also the distinction between a list *display* and the `list` value it produces. Given `a = 10` and `g = 20`, the two list displays `[1,2,3,a,4,g]` and `[1,2,3,10,4,20]` both produce equivalent instances of `list`.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mre].

Comment: @chepner no it is a list of integers and then that integer is replaced by some thing on a certain condition.

All I want is to have double quotes on every list element. the list is created by the range function.

Comment: '''n = 5

rangeOfList = range(1,n+1)


list1 = list(rangeOfList)
print(list1)


condition1 = "FizzBuzz"
condition2 = "Fizz"
condition3 = "Buzz"

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] % 3 == 0 and list1[i] % 5 == 0:
        list1[i] = condition1

    elif list1[i] % 3 == 0:
        list1[i] =condition2

    elif list1[i] % 5 == 0:
        list1[i] =condition3

print(list1)'''

it prints  [1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz']
i want double quotes

Comment: @AbdulBasitNiazi You need to include the code that defines `newst` (including the values of `a` and `g` if applicable), or the result of calling `print(newst)`.  `a` is not an int value.

Comment: @AbdulBasitNiazi your most recent update resolved the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), but didn't clarify the issue asked about in the comments (namely, whether the issue was with a list or the printed representation of the list). Note that there's still an issue: the question mentions that "[your] code produces an error", but doesn't say [what the error is](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're looking for it to convert all elements of the list to strings:

```
a = 'a'
g = 'g'
myList = [1,2,3,a,4,g]

print(myList)

[1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 'g']

myList = list(map(str,myList))

['1', '2', '3', 'a', '4', 'g']
```

Python's list representation uses single quotes though.   If you want them to be double quotes, you'll need to convert them  yourself:

```
print(myList.__repr__().replace("'",'"')) 

["1", "2", "3", "a", "4", "g"]
```

*Note that this may cause some inconsistencies if some of the strings contain single quotes themselves. You would then need more sophisticated formatting logic:*

```
print("["+", ".join(map('"{}"'.format,myList))+"]")
```

Comment: it works fine on ide but has some flows on leet code. any way thanks